deep compare 2 objects in ts and return only value that is updated with generics
const getChangedValues = (values, initialValues) => {
  const compareObjects = (obj1, obj2) => {
    return Object.entries(obj1).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
        const nestedChanges = compareObjects(value, obj2[key]);
        if (Object.keys(nestedChanges).length > 0) {
          acc[key] = nestedChanges;
        }
      } else {
        if (obj2 && obj2[key] !== value) {
          acc[key] = value;
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };

  return compareObjects(values, initialValues);
};


this is a js function which return only those key with object which are updated even if any key is nested and it has object in it .it will only return that nested object key and values if any of nested key value is updated . i want to write this fn in ts with generics and without loose types
okay want to write down function ts with generics which takes 2 oldobj and newobj and return new object out of it with only those keys which are updated without using types any, unknown or never

TypeScript only works at compile time. It does not know any values at runtime and it cannot evaluate and generate types at runtime. As a suggestion, you can use a generic type for the values object and return a deep partial of the generic type instead. Or, if it applies in your case, you can try to find a package that performs a diff on 2 objects.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


You should return a recursive partial of obj1's type
You can use the main function for the recursion

This errors r.child as possibly undefined, but possibly TS can infer it not being undefined in this case. The problematic line is:
const nestedChanges = obj2[key] ? getChangedValues(value, (obj2 as T)[key]) : {};

where TS can't infer that key is presented in obj2.
Playground
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
    T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object | undefined ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
    T[P];
};

const getChangedValues = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>>(obj1: T, obj2: RecursivePartial<T>) => {
    const out = {} as typeof obj2;
    for(const key in obj1){
        const value = obj1[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
            const nestedChanges = obj2[key] ? getChangedValues(value, (obj2 as T)[key]) : {};
            if (Object.keys(nestedChanges).length > 0) {
                out[key] = nestedChanges as typeof obj2[typeof key];
            }
        } else {
            if (obj2[key] !== value) {
                out[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
};

const obj1 = {
    child:{
        test: true,
        test2: false
    },
    child2: true,
    child3: false
}
const obj2 = {
    child:{
        test: false,
        test2: false
    },
    child2: false,
    child4:true,
}

const r = getChangedValues(obj1, obj2);
console.log(r.child.test);

